# MySQL LENGTH() > 0 and NOT NULL not getting expected results

Tags: mysql, select, string-length, notnull

Viewing my result set, I see a blank field despite my conditions.

I tried selecting:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE LENGTH(column) > 0 AND column IS NOT NULL
```

i also tried:

```
WHERE LENGTH(column) <> 0 AND column IS NOT NULL
```

but, I'm still seeing a blank field.

In my SELECT, I tried checking the contents of the field:

```
SELECT column, LENGTH(column), HEX(column)
```

etc...

But, they both come up as 0 and seemingly empty, respectively.

What did I miss here?

Comment: You're saying that `SELECT LENGTH(column)` returns `0`?

Comment: Correct. LENGTH(column) returns 0

Comment: deleting my answer as you alreay tried it..which language are you using to retrieve the data, can you post the code?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

`SELECT co.contact_email, LENGTH(co.contact_email), HEX(co.contact_email), co.contact_client, cl.client_name
FROM contacts as co 
JOIN clients as cl ON co.contact_client = cl.client_oldid
WHERE cl.client_status = 2 order by cl.client_name
AND LENGTH(co.contact_email) > 0 
AND co.contact_email is not null
AND TRIM(co.contact_EMAIL) <> ''`

Comment: Also, the field attributes are: varchar(80) and cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT 
      ....  
  FROM contacts as co 
  JOIN clients as cl 
    ON co.contact_client = cl.client_oldid 
  -- this starts a where clause
  WHERE cl.client_status = 2 
  -- ORDER BY ends a WHERE clause, and goes only for ordering:
  order by 
    cl.client_name  
    AND LENGTH(co.contact_email) > 0  -- so, order by result of this 0 or 1
    AND co.contact_email is not null  -- then, order by result of this 0 or 1
    AND TRIM(co.contact_EMAIL) <> '   -- then, order by result of this 0 or 1
```

Comment: Well don't I feel sheepish. Thanks everyone.